# Template Function: How to make a template function with a template class as an argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to make a template for a function that has a template class in its argument list?

I would like to make one template for statSelection() and statInsertion() that would allow me to test different sorting algorithms without having to create a separate stat function for each type of sorting algorithm I am testing.  (My sorting algorithms are template classes)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "FileGen.h"
#include "FileRead.h"
#include "SelectionSort.h"
#include "SelectionSort.cpp"
#include "InsertionSort.h"
#include "InsertionSort.cpp"

using namespace std;

void statSelection(int[], int[], Selection<int>, Selection<int>);
void statInsertion(int[], int[], Insertion<int>, Insertion<int>);

int main () 
{
    FileGen fileGen;
    FileRead fileRead;
    Selection<int> selectHundred;
    Selection<int> selectThousand;
    Insertion<int> insertionHundred;
    Insertion<int> insertionThousand;
    int valuesHundred[100];
    int valuesThousand[1000];
    fileGen.generateFiles();
    fileRead.readFiles(valuesHundred, valuesThousand);
    statSelection(valuesHundred, valuesThousand, selectHundred, selectThousand);
    fileGen.generateFiles();
    fileRead.readFiles(valuesHundred, valuesThousand);
    statInsertion(valuesHundred, valuesThousand, insertionHundred, insertionThousand);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void statSelection(int vHundred[], int vThousand[], Selection<int> sHundred, Selection<int> sThousand)
{
    cout << "One Hundred Items" << endl;
    sHundred.SelectionSort(vHundred, 100);
    sHundred.selectionSortPreformance();
    cout << "One Thousand Items" << endl;
    sThousand.SelectionSort(vThousand, 1000);
    sThousand.selectionSortPreformance();
}

void statInsertion(int vHundred[], int vThousand[], Insertion<int> iHundred, Insertion<int> iThousand)
{
    cout << "One Hundred Items" << endl;
    iHundred.InsertionSort(vHundred, 100);
    iHundred.insertionSortPreformance();
    cout << "One Thousand Items" << endl;
    iThousand.InsertionSort(vThousand, 1000);
    iThousand.insertionSortPreformance();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some short code sample that illustrates what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I really appreciate everyone responses.  Let me try to clarify what I am asking:  This driver file works correctly to print out each sorting algorithms number of swaps and comparisons made.  The sorting classes are class templates and everything works correctly.  My questions is how can I create a template for my stats function when it takes template classes as arguments?  I would like to be able to call stats passing a Insertion class or a Selection class(or other sorting classes), but both of these classes are also templates.  Is it possible to do this without polymorphism?

Comment: It is if you name your functions the same.

Comment: I still don't get it, but I think you should be able to do what you need using one of the two examples I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would rather use polymorphism.**  (The solution without polymorphism can be found after a horizontal rule)

I would inherit both `Insertion<_Tp>` and `Selection<_Tp>` from an abstract class (interface) called `ISortable<_Tp>`, and name `.InsertionSort` and `.SelectionSort` member functions simply as `.Sort` (which would be a virtual member function of Sortable<_Tp>).

```
template<typename _Tp>
class ISortable<_Tp>{
public:
    virtual void Sort(_Tp *, int)=0; // btw functions are usually lowercase
    virtual void Performance()=0; 
};

template<typename _Tp>
class InsertionSort<_Tp> : public Sortable<_Tp>{
//...
    virtual void Sort(_Tp *, int); 
    virtual void Performance(); 
};
//...
```

So your function can be written like this:

```
void statSelection(int[], int[], Sortable<int>&, Sortable<int>&);

void statSelection(int[], int[], Sortable<int>&sHundred, Sortable<int>&)
{
//...
  sHundred.Sort(vHundred, 100);
  sHundred.Performance();
//...
}
```

---

**Solution without polymorphism:**

It is possible to do, just name BOTH your sort and performance functions **with the same name**.

Then

```
template<typename _Tp_sortable>
void statGeneral(int[], int[], _Tp_sortable sHundred, _Tp_sortable)
{
//...
  sHundred.Sort(vHundred, 100);
  sHundred.Performance();
//...
}
```

The examples: (Im not sure if you actually need the `<Selection<int> >` part after the function, but I'd call it with it.)

```
statGeneral<Selection<int> >(valuesHundred, valuesThousand, selectHundred, selectThousand);
statGeneral<Insertion<int> >(valuesHundred, valuesThousand, insertionHundred, insertionThousand);
```

Comment: Could you explain your second suggestion in more detail?  How would i pass the argument list to the class template in this scenario (ie Insertion<int>)

Comment: Sure, check my update, I copied two lines from your main function in this new form. If it would not work for some reason, let me know, and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are after, but this is a function template that has a class template parameter.

```
// class template
template <typename T> class Foo {};

// function template
template <typename T>
T doSomething(const Foo<T>& f) { .... }
```

If you want to be able to specify the class template as a template parameter, then you need a "template template parameter":

```
// class templates
template <typename T> class Foo {};
template <typename T> class Bar {};

template <template<class> class T1, class T2>
T2 doSomething(const T1<T2>& f);

Foo<int> f;
Bar<double> b;
int n = doSomething(f);
double x = doSomething(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
template <typename T>
void statSelection(T vHundred[], T vThousand[], Selection<T> sHundred, Selection<T> sThousand);

template <typename T>
void statInsertion(T vHundred[], T vThousand[], Insertion<T> iHundred, Insertion<T> iThousand);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class like this:

```
template <class T>
class Sortclass
{
public:
    virtual void sort(T array[] , int size) = 0;
    virtual void preformance() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class AsortClass : public Sortclass<T> 
{
public:
    virtual sort(T array[] , int size)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    virtual void preformance()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
};

template <class T>
void stat(T vHundred[], T vThousand[], Sortclass<T>& iHundred, Sortclass<T>& iThousand)
{
    cout << "One Hundred Items" << endl;
    iHundred.sort(vHundred, 100);
    iHundred.preformance();
    cout << "One Thousand Items" << endl;
    iThousand.sort(vThousand, 1000);
    iThousand.preformance();
}
```

then you can inherit from this class and implement the sort funktion.
with this you can change the sort algorythm realy easy without changing the stat function.

its called strategy pattern see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: 1. your code is wrong at the stat function. 2. it does not differ from my solution.

Comment: Sorry, but your class code is also wrong... care to see my answer before posting?

Comment: I think I owe you an explanation why is your code is still wrong. If you intend to do polymorphism, you need to declare all your functions virtual (just like I did in my answer). Otherwise the program will always call the function in the base class. (Btw that results currently in linking error in your code.) Also it is advised that all functions in interfaces are declared abstract by adding "=0" after the declaration.